# Bulk update of contacts with related records

Tags: dynamics-crm, excel-online

I have a requirement to perform a bulk update on Contacts using **Excel Online**, but there is a set of entities with a N:N relationship to Contacts that need to be filled in order to facilitate data input.

As it's impossible to edit this kind of relation for each contact record in Excel Online, I would like to receive recommendations to overcome that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s going to be a manual exercise of having multiple files/sheets, with the help of `vlookup` or some **macros**  - you have to manipulate (copy/paste?) the result to Excel online sheet.